# Converting number data from CSV to a float and getting average in Python

Tags: python

I have the following python function that takes an input of directory and the file name.

It reads from a CSV file which can have a line with 'null' as the value.

```
tps.csv

1
2
3
4
null
5
6
```

The moment it reads 'null' from the csv, it gives me an error (below) even though I have an if condition to skip when it reads 'null.'

ValueError: could not convert string to float: null

Code:

```
def computeMean(dir_name, filename):
    csv_filename = '{}/{}'.format(dir_name, filename)
    numbers = []
    with open(csv_filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line is not 'null':
                number_on_line = float(line)
                numbers.append(number_on_line)

    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```

What do I need to add or change so that it ignores/skips non-numerical values?

Comment: Can you please share the error/traceback?

Comment: Try changing if condition to - if 'null' in line instead of if line is not null

Answer (score 2):

In your file, a line ends with `\n`. You have then the string `null\n`, not `null`.
The best way to handle that is probably to use `strip` method, which is designed for that:

```
if line.strip() != 'null':
    ...
```

Note that `is` is not used here. [Because `is` doesn't work as you think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504742/3077939).

Answer (score 1):

Use a comparison instead of `is not`:

```
if line != 'null':
```

`is`/`is not` checks for object identity, while `==`/`!=` compares the value of objects. In your case, the line has the same value as the constant string `null`, but they are different objects.

Note that due to the internals of Python, comparing strings with `is` will work sometimes, but not always.

```
>>> 'foo' is 'foo'
True
>>> 'foobar'[:3] is 'foo'
False
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

`is` operates differently than `str in str` or `str == str`, thus the error

I believe you can do this with a list-comprehension

```
with open(csv_filename) as f:
    numbers = [float(l.strip()) for l in f if l != 'null']
return 0 if len(numbers) == 0 else sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the shortest solution that I've found. I've combined this with @aluriak answer and added the .strip() in the list comprehension

for l in f if l.strip() != 'null'